# display format for gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a grid named 'GridView1' contains two columns 'Date' and 'Session Details' I am displaying like this way only:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" OnRowCommand="ScheduleGridView_RowCommand" 
    runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="60px"
    Style="text-align: center" Width="869px" EnableViewState="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date" DataField="Date">
            <HeaderStyle Width="80px" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="" HeaderText="Session Detais" />
    </Columns>
```

But here I need to display 3 column sections downside Session details without any column borders for each dates, how can I achieve this.

```
Date                                                                SessionDetails

06-04-2010                       Time-(value from database)         Topic-(value from database)    Head-(value from database)


-------                               ------------------               -------------------            ----------------------
```

Comment: i dont know how to add subcolumns here without borders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to use a `TemplateField` to define the layout yourself. Something like this will do it:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" OnRowCommand="ScheduleGridView_RowCommand" 
    runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="60px"
    Style="text-align: center" Width="869px" EnableViewState="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date" DataField="Date">
            <HeaderStyle Width="80px" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Session Details
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <span class="col"><%# Eval("Time") %></span>
                <span class="col"><%# Eval("Topic") %></span>
                <span class="col"><%# Eval("Head") %></span>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Note:** You'll have to replace `Time`, `Topic`, and `Head` with your real values if they differ. You can then style the placement of the 3 `span` tags with a style such as:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .col { width: 100px; float: left; }
</style>
```